# Logging a user in and creating a session

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a bunch of functions that return promises and need to chain them together. However, it's currently difficult to read and I would expect it to be even harder to maintain.

I have a function that performs the following actions:

1. Logs off any inactive users.
2. Verifies a user's credentials.
3. Creates a session and logs the user in.

Is there a better way?

```
generateToken: function (email, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Kill inactive sessions first
        module.exports.destroyInactive()
        .then(() => {
            //Verify that the password matches the user
            users.checkPassword(email, password, sharedSecret)
            .then((user) => {
                //Check if there is another user already signed in, if there is then we can't
                //produce another token until they are signed out.
                signedon.getByEmailAddressThisProcess(email)
                .then((result) => {
                    let rows = result[0];

                    if (rows.length > 0)
                        return reject('A user with email: ' + email + ' is already logged in.');

                    //Get the current XPROCESS.
                    xprocess.getByProcessId(process.pid)
                    .then((xproc) => {
                        //Create a brand new session object
                        let session = generateSession(user);

                        //Save the session in the signed on table.
                        signedon.signin(session, xproc.pid)
                        .then(() => {
                            resolve(parseSessionToToken(session));
                        },
                        reject);
                    },
                    reject);
                },
                reject);
            },
            reject);
        },
        reject);
    });
},
```

Comment: Why is the client doing all those checks? The client should just try to log in with a single call and get a "forbidden" or "granted" kind of response, the server should take care of all the rest.

Comment: @ChatterOne This code **is** on the server. The client makes a request to a login API endpoint and is returned either a token or an authentication error.

Comment: Ok, you should probably add a tag to your question then, is it node.js ?

Comment: @ChatterOne Ok yes, I've just re-tagged it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Potential improvements**

```
generateToken(email, password) {
  let user, session;

  return module.exports.destroyInactive()
    .then(() => users.checkPassword(email, password, sharedSecret))
    .then(_user => user = _user)
    .then(() => signedon.getByEmailAddressThisProcess(email))
    .then(([rows]) => {
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        return Promise.reject(`A user with email: ${email} is already logged in`);
      }

      return xprocess.getByProcessId(process.pid);
    }).then(xproc => {
      session = generateSession(user);

      return signedon.signin(session, xproc.pid);
    }).then(() => parseSessionToToken(session));
}
```

Your method falls into the [nested promises antipattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#nested-promises), very similar to the classic callback pyramid of doom.

This solution relies on chaining promises. Since we need the variables `user` and `session` in non-adjacent promises we need to have references of them outside of the promise chain.

Since you are already using Promises which are an ES6 feature, you can take advantage of extra ES6 goodness. See [es6-features.org](http://es6-features.org/) for more.

**ES6 features**

[Enhanced object method properties](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties)

`generateToken: function (email, password)` can be simplified by using  to `generateToken(email, password)`

[Arrow Function Expression Bodies](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies)

`users.checkPassword(...)` is implicitly returned. Since this is a Promise, the chain won't continue to be executed until the returned Promise is resolved/rejected. This means we can just return the promise and not have to continue to nest using `checkPassword(...).then(...)`

[Array Matching](http://es6-features.org/#ArrayMatching)

`let rows = result[0]` can be simplified to `rows = [result]`, which can then be used as the resolve parameter (`([rows]) => ...`)

[Promise.reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

Returning `Promise.reject` allows us to reject the Promise without nesting.

[Template Literals/String Interpolation](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation)

Provide a (subjectively) more readable solution by not having to concatenate strings with variables.

`'A user with email: ' + email + ' is already logged in.'`

becomes

```
`A user with email: ${email} is already logged in`
```

[Arrow Function Statement Bodies](http://es6-features.org/#StatementBodies)

Since we are doing multiple things inside the `rows` Promise,  we use `=>` statement bodies.

Due to this we need to explicitly return the Promise (so that the chain doesn't continue to execute until the Promise is resolved/rejected). Otherwise `undefined` will be resolved, not waiting for the Promise.

**Note:**

Nowhere are you catching rejected promises using `catch`, are you catching a rejected `generateToken` attempt?

Promises can greatly improve readability and remove nested callbacks when used correctly, but it is important to not allow them to "swallow" errors. At the very least make sure to log rejected Promises. A simple `somePromise(...).catch(console.error)` is better than nothing. Prefer `console.error` over `console.log` when possible since it's more "noisy".